# Current Year To Date, Last Year To Date, and Other

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to classify a set of dates as either 'Cur. YTD', 'Lst. YTD', or 'Other'.  YTD is based upon getdate().  I have a temp table for testing that has a single column called 'calendar_date' of type DATETIME.  I came up with this logic and it appears to work.  I'm just wondering if this approach makes good sense from a performance perspective or if something else might be better.

```
select calendar_date,
case when (MONTH(calendar_date) < MONTH(getdate()))
     or (MONTH(calendar_date) = MONTH (getdate())
         AND DAY(calendar_date) <= DAY(getdate())) then
case when YEAR(calendar_date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) then 'CYTD'
when YEAR(calendar_date) = YEAR(getdate()) - 1 then 'LYTD'
else 'Other'
end
else 'Other'
end as Tim_Tag_YTD
from #temp1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic looks good and will work as-is.

An alternative which simplifies a little, which assumes you have no *future* data.

```
select
  calendar_date,
  Tim_Tag_YTD = case DATEDIFF(YEAR, calendar_date, GETDATE())
                when 0 then 'CYTD'
                when 1 then 'LYTD'
                else 'Other'
                end
from #temp1;
```

In the case of your logic, you are explicitly putting future data into 'Other', which you can also do like this:

```
select
  calendar_date,
  Tim_Tag_YTD = case when calendar_date > GETDATE() then 'Other' else
                    case DATEDIFF(YEAR, calendar_date, GETDATE())
                    when 0 then 'CYTD'
                    when 1 then 'LYTD'
                    else 'Other'
                    end
                end
from #temp1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes something unintuitive performs faster.   Something like this might be worth a shot.

```
set variable @FirstOfLastYear to Jan 1 of last year
using sql server date functions

set @FirstOfThisYear = DateAdd(year, 1, @FirstOfLastYear)

select 'last year' period
, whatever else you need
from #temp1 where calendar_date >= @FirstOfLastYear
and calendar_date < @FirstOfThisYear
union
select 'this year' period
, whatever else you need
from #temp1 where calendar_date >= @FirstOfThisYear
and calendar_date < getDate ()
union
select 'other' period
, whatever else you need
from #temp1 where calendar_date <= @FirstOfLastYear
or calendar_date > getdate()
```

You'll never know unless you try.